# How do I parse an array/matrix from a text file while preserving its structure?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and am trying to write a script that will parse the data contained between each pair of headers in the text file below.

```
<Keywords> 
GTO
</Keywords>
<NumberofNuclei>
2
</NumberofNuclei>
<Nuclear Charges> 
6.0
8.0
1.0
1.0
</Nuclear Charges>
<Primitive Exponents>
8.264000000000e+01  1.241000000000e+01  2.824000000000e+00   
8.989000000000e-02  2.292000000000e+00  2.292000000000e+00  
8.380000000000e-01  8.380000000000e-01  2.920000000000e-01 
</Primitive Exponents>
```

My attempt at a code that can do this is shown below. However, I am having difficulty parsing the matrix under Primitive Exponents while preserving its 3x3 structure. I don't want it written as a list.

```
with open('toysystem.txt','r') as f:
 data = f.read()
 nc = re.findall(r'<Nuclear Charges>(.*?)</Nuclear Charges>',data,re.DOTALL)
 nc1 = [elem.replace('\n',',').strip(',') for elem in nc]
 non = re.findall(r'<NumberofNuclei>(.*?)</NumberofNuclei>',data,re.DOTALL)
 non1 = int("".join(map(str, non)))
 kw = re.findall(r'<Keywords>(.*?)</Keywords>',data,re.DOTALL)
 kw1 = "".join(map(str, kw)).replace('\n','')
 pe = np.array(re.findall(r'<Primitive Exponents>(.*?)</Primitive Exponents>',data,re.DOTALL))
```

Any ideas on how to approach this problem/modify my code to extract the matrix as is (a 3x3 array)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with this because `findall()` returns a list, in this case a list with one element, and `numpy.array()` reasonably translates a 1-list into an array with one element. Some work is needed to get the string into a 3x3 matrix *before* you ask numpy to turn it into an array.

```
pe_match = re.search(r'<Primitive Exponents>(.*?)</Primitive Exponents>',data,re.DOTALL)
#  Extract the numbers from the enclosing tags and split into 3 lines
matrix = pe_match.group(1).strip("\n").split("\n")
#  Turn each line into a 3-list
matrix2 = [m.split() for m in matrix]
pe = np.array(matrix2)
```

This gives you a 3x3 numpy array of strings.

```
array([['8.264000000000e+01', '1.241000000000e+01', '2.824000000000e+00'],
       ['8.989000000000e-02', '2.292000000000e+00', '2.292000000000e+00'],
       ['8.380000000000e-01', '8.380000000000e-01', '2.920000000000e-01']], 
      dtype='|S18')
```

That will of course need further conversion before you can use it, but your question was about the matrix structure.